# C# Serialization Issue

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm having some trouble with binary serialization in C#... I should add that I'm a relative noob with C#, so please explain in simple terms :)

Anyway, I have this class (truncated for clarity):

```
[Serializable]
public class Player : Ship {
```

And Ship looks like this (again, truncated):

```
[Serializable]
public class Ship : TiledActor {
    public float MaxUserTurnPerSecond;
    public float RemainingShieldStrength;
    public float MaxShieldStrength;
    public float ShieldRechargeRate;
    public float ShieldRechargeDelay;
    public Color ShieldColor;
    public float ThrusterAccelerationScale;
    public Color RippleTrailColor;
    public float MinimumRippleSpeed;
    public float MaxEnergy;
    public float CurrentEnergy;
    public float EnergyRechargeRate;
    public float MaxSecondaryAmmoCapacity;
    public int CurrentSecondaryAmmoCount;
    public Weapon PrimaryWeapon;
    public Weapon SecondaryWeapon;
    protected ShieldActor ShieldTex;

    [NonSerialized]
    public MoXNA.ParticleMachines.PM_Explosion_Particle_Count ExplosionSize;
    [NonSerialized]
    protected MoXNA.ParticleMachines.MinSpeedRippleTrail rippleTrail;

    /* ... Truncated here */
```

So, as you can see, I wish to serialize the Player class. However, when I try this, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Type
>   'MoXNA.ParticleMachines.MinSpeedRippleTrail'
>   in Assembly 'SpaceshipInABox,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as
>   serializable.

The odd thing here is that I marked **rippleTrail** (which is the *MinSpeedRippleTrail* object) as [NonSerialized]... I don't want to serialize it (it's just a visual effect).

I used "Find all references" and that's the only *MinSpeedRippleTrail* object in the entire program, so what the hell?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code where this error is thrown? Which data you are trying to write and what not.

Comment: Are the types : Color, Weapon, ShieldActor serializable ?

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't work, but you can give the following a try. Try adding `Serializable` to the `MinSpeedRippleTrail` class/struct anyhow, perhaps even though the `NonSerialized` attribute is applied, it still checks first whether it can be serialized?

Comment: There's no decent explanation for this.  Only a crummy one, your program is loading an old version of the assembly.  Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to double-check this.  Also watch out for *deserializing* old data.

Answer (score 4):

The usual problem here is an event. BinaryFormatter includes events, which many people don't expect. The event field must be marked, for example:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

It is painfully easy to get an event subscription that you didn't anticipate break the serializer (a capture class, perhaps).

However, I also encourage you:

- don't use public fields; use properties
- don't use BinaryFormatter - it bites most people eventually; and bites hard

If you want a binary serializer that works with XNA, consider protobuf-net; it is faster, has smaller output, adapts to change more gracefully ... and is free. Caveat: I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML serialization you can use [XmlIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx), otherwise change rippleTrail member to a method. for example: GetRippleTrail()

Comment: Still doesn't look like a solution to his problem.

Comment: Yes I misread it. I won't update my answer, maybe someone will face same issue with XML serialization too :)

Comment: I can respect that; the "long tail" etc